# ReferenceError: Can't find variable X when calling JS function (or variable) from HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, referenceerror

I am trying to call a function in an external JavaScript file from an HTML-file. The goal is to work with the content of a form there.

I tried so many things and always got the Error "*ReferenceError: Can't find variable: X*"

- The positioning of the jquery javascript file loading
- The positioning of the `<script src="XXX">` call
- Calling the function from the button "onclick" or the form "onsubmit"
- Trying to call the javascript file from an embedded script in the HTML

This is what my JavaScript file and my HTML looks like right now:

```js
function submit(e) {

  answerText = document.getElementById("text").value;
  // Do something with it.

}
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/scripts/debug_alerts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="validation-form" onsubmit="return submit(e)">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="text" id="text" placeholder="Text" required>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="submit(e)">Send</button>
  </form>
</body>
```

I also tried

```js
function doSomething() {

  // Do something

}
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/scripts/debug_alerts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="validation-form" onsubmit="return submit(e)">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="text" id="text" placeholder="Text" required>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="submit(e)">Send</button>
  </form>
  <script>
    function submit(e) {
      doSomething();
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

In both cases, it returned the same error over and over again: "*ReferenceError: Can't find variable: X*". In the first example, X being "submit" and in the second "doSomething".

All help is very welcome. I know there are similar headlines here, but non of the solutions did anything for me.

Comment: Is the error message you get `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $` or `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: submit`?

Comment: The error you get in your examples is different, and relates to `e` being not defined.

Comment: I am getting a different error here like `Uncaught ReferenceError: e is not defined`

Comment: Can you provide the *exact* error message please?

Comment: Looks like you just need to change `onclick="submit(e)"` to `onclick="submit(this)"` or even just `onclick="submit()"` if you don't need the event - or use jquery events instead of inline ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey so when I ran the code without the e as a parameter for the submit function in the html it didn't give me the error. I think it may be because the e is the place holder for the text of the submit function in this case. Hope this helps.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/scripts/debug_alerts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="validation-form" onsubmit="return submit(e)">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="text" id="text" placeholder="Text" required>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="submit()">Send</button>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function submit(e) {

            answerText = document.getElementById("text").value;
            // Do something with it.


        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```